# Can the acceleration of a decelerating particle be positive?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration

let's say you have friction on a surface that makes particle A decelerate constantly at $-0.75 ms^{-2}$. when you draw a velocity-time graph to graph this you will get a line $y=mx+c$ with a negative gradient. But let's say the particle turns back, its velocity will now be negative, but its acceleration is still supposed to be negative due to friction. But when you draw this the gradient of that part would be positive. I'm guessing it's just how it's represented on a velocity-time graph. However, I'm using the suvat equations of motion to find an expression for displacement and I'm not getting the correct answer as I'm putting acceleration to be negative. my question is, why is it positive? it's not like gravity. friction is supposed to slow things down no matter what direction they're traveling in.

Comment: You get to define the positive direction at the start of the problem.

Comment: yes, i know that, David.

Comment: Then you already know the answer to your question,

Comment: unfortunately, i don't.

Answer (score 1):

> my question is, why is it positive? it's not like gravity. friction is supposed to slow things down no matter what direction they're traveling in.

Friction reduces the velocity difference between two objects.  In the case where we're talking about friction against the ground (which is assumed to be at rest), that means that friction makes the velocity move *toward zero*.   Toward zero is not always negative.

$$a = \frac{v_f - v_i}{t}$$

What is the acceleration if friction changes the velocity from $10 \text{m/s}$ to $0\text{m/s}$ over $5\text{s}$?

What is the acceleration if friction changes the velocity from $-10 \text{m/s}$ to $0\text{m/s}$ over $5\text{s}$?

In both scenarios friction is slowing (reducing the relative velocity) of the object.  But the acceleration is not the same.

Comment: could you please elaborate for me (i'm not a student of physics but i'll try my best to understand) ? you seem to be making a point. tho, i'm not quite getting it.

Comment: Your velocity can be negative.  If it is negative, then changing the speed to zero is a positive acceleration.

Comment: ok.  but the particle is still decelerating right?

Comment: I wouldn't use the word "decelerating" in a physics problem where it might be misunderstood.  I would say the speed is decreasing.

Comment: @ilovecupcakes Positive acceleration doesn't mean increasing velocity, it depends on the direction you chose for velocity